# Auto Sort - Stop going back to the top of the table

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code where once I select someone in the "Associate" column the table automatically sorts the data.

It takes me back to the top of the table.

I have to scroll back down.

I would like to stay on the row I just completed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#ALL],[Date]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
    :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Time]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
    :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Table1[[#All],[Associate]]")) Is Nothing Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Target.Activate` maybe?

Comment: Inside a sheet code module, `Me` refers to the sheet itself, so you can use that in place of `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe as simple as adding a final `Target.Activate`.

Comment: Where do I added it? After the End if?

Comment: I assume you want before - activate after sorting.